# Help with rough Shading in blender

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to make a shading in blender 2.8 that looks like the handle of the Glock

like in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Try some of the **Musgrave** texture ...

[image]

Comment: ... which could also be used as a bump-map, if that's enough for the OP

Comment: It does not work

Comment: What do you mean? Be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a Noise Texture, softened by mixing with white. I would also give a small subsurface value to give it that "rubber" look. Remember to change the Subsurface Radius values to be equal so the subsurface color is not tinted red.

(Also, I know it's hard to see from the image, but I'm using *Object* texture coordinates )
[image: Rubber]